# Database.Saveresult into a list of object

Tags: custom-object

I have a list of `Line_item__c` which is storing my line items as

```
List<Line_Item__c> toInsertList = new List<Line_Item__c>();
```

I am inserting these records in database using the below statement :

```
List<Database.Saveresult> insertResults=Database.insert(toInsertList, false);
```

Now the result is stored in insertResults which is of `Database.Saveresult` type but i want the result in a list of `Line_Item__c`. How do i do this. If anyone has a idea, it will be of great use.

Answer (score 5):

Database.Saveresult will not give results as per the object that you insert/update. Instead you will get the ID of created record and then you could query the data as you like. For example,

```
List<Database.Saveresult> insertResults=Database.insert(toInsertList, false);
List<Id> listOfIds = new List<Id>();
for (Database.SaveResult sr : insertResults) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        listOfIds.add(sr.getId());
    }
}
List<Line_Item__c> listOfLineItems = [Select Id, Name from Line_Item__c where Id in :listOfIds];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sethu. As per your suggestion my code is working now :)

Comment: @user12051 you can also express your gratitude by voting on this anwer on the left of it. By clicking the (V) button you also indicate this answer as the accepted answer, which will show other users that your question has been answered.

Comment: @user12051, As Samuel mentioned, please mark it as answer if you find it useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will iterate over the [Database.SaveResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult) list and add all the successfully inserted `Line_Item__c` records in to a List called `successLineItems` and all the failures into the `failedLineItems` `List`

```
List<Database.SaveResult> insertResults = Database.insert(toInsertList, false);
Set<Id> successIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Database.SaveResult insertResult : insertResults) {
    if (insertResult.isSuccess()) {
        successIds.add(insertResult.getId());
    }
}
List<Line_Item__c> successLineItems = new List<Line_Item__c>();
List<Line_Item__c> failedLineItems = new List<Line_Item__c>();
for (Line_Item__c  li : toInsertList) {
    if (successIds.contains(li.Id)) {
        successLineItems.add(li);
    } else {
        failedLineItems.add(li);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. For me important was to get know exactly which inserted record succeed or failed. I wrote a method to handle this scenario:

```
/**
     * @description Method to insert objects to DataBase with improved audit
     * @param sObjects - sObjects to be insert
     * @param field - field that identifies Saveresult with inserted object
     * @return map where key is a value from field specified as param: field
     * and the value is Save result for sObject which is identified by key
     */
    public static Map<String,Database.SaveResult> improvedInsert(List<SObject> sObjects, Schema.sObjectField field) {
        Map<String,Database.SaveResult> saveResultByField = new Map<String,Database.SaveResult>();
        List<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.insert(sObjects, false);
        for (Integer i = 0;i<sObjects.size();i++) {
            saveResultByField.put((String)sObjects.get(i).get(field),results.get(i));
        }
        return  saveResultByField;
    }
```

The above method gives You a `Map` where the key is specified as parameter field value, and the value is the `SaveResult`/`UpsertResult` object.

You can see my project [on GitHub](https://github.com/patrykacc/sfdc_utils/blob/master/src/classes/Utils.cls).

Comment: Please do not just post links. Post the relevant content within your answer or delete it